# Position elements relative to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append duplicates of letters beneath the main letter when I hover over them...

And then dynamically/gradually move the letters down till they reach the bottom of the browser.

My issue is that the location of all the appended letters (spans) just update as a group when I hover over the next letter, which is happening on the left. What I want is on the right:

[image]

**Code:**

I'm using jsLettering (`$(".title").lettering();`) to break up each letter in`<h1 class="title">2014</h1>` into separate spans

so 2014 would be

```
<span class="char1">2</span>
<span class="char2">0</span>
<span class="char3">1</span>
<span class="char4">4</span>
```

Then on hover of each span, I'm trying to create and append a copy of the letter to `$('.fallingLetters')`, then make the letters animate down towards the bottom.

**HTML snippet:**

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><h1 class="title">2014</h1></div>
            <div class="fallingLetters"></div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript snippet:**

```
        $("h1 span").mouseenter(function () {       
            var 
                letter = $(this).text(),
                val = $(this);

            $('.fallingLetters').append("<span>" + letter + "</span>");

            $('.fallingLetters span').css({"position" : "absolute"});
            $('.fallingLetters span')css({"left" : val.position().left+100});                                                           
            $('.fallingLetters span').css({"top" : val.position().top+150});        
        });

         setInterval(function(){ 
            moveSpans();
         }, 100);
    });

    function moveSpans() {
        $(".fallingLetters span").each(function (index, val) {  
            if ($(".fallingLetters span").length > 30) {        
                $(".fallingLetters").empty();
            }
            $(val).css("top","+=5");                                    
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an HTML snippet for this so that we can see exactly what you're animating? I have to guess a little based on your javascript code.

Comment: @user3446496 see update above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell what kind of effect you really want to achieve so I am guessing a bit. I did the fiddle before the HTML was posted but it should be easily adapted with your classes.

Let me know if this is kind of what you are looking for: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/vSK5v/)**

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("h1 span").mouseenter(function () {
        var letter = $(this).clone(),
            parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.append(letter);

        letter.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": $(this).position().left,
            "top": parent.height()
        });
        letter.animate({"top": $(window).outerHeight()}, 5000, "linear", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });    
});
```

HTML

```
<h1>
    <span>2</span><span>0</span><span>1</span><span>4</span>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
h1 > span {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Wow nice work Mathias. Is `animate` native js or jquery? Nice solution! Also, I noticed when the letters are removed, the whole container shifts a little bit, then shifts back

Comment: @Growler `animate`is jQuery, https://api.jquery.com/animate/ The shifting might be because of the scollbar appearing and disappearing, I updated the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

When you set the position of the falling letter to 'absolute', the letter no longer takes up space on the page, so the val.position().left will be the same for all the letters - that's why they're stacking on top of one another. You have two options: 
 1. Set the positions of the letters manually and individually, that way you can space them out properly. 
 2. wrap the four spans that hold the letters in a single 'div' element and then animate the position of the div that holds all four letters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that in the HTML:

```
<div class="lineOne">
    <span>2</span>
    <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="lineTwo">
    <span>0</span>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div class="lineThree">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="lineFour">
    <span>4</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Then just make `.lineOne` as `position: relative;` and the span elements `position: absolute;`. Then the absolute positions of the span elements are relative to the div container. So you can change the position relative to the container. With little tweaks it should do what you want to achieve.